# Value of $f'(3^{1/5})$ from the given differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A function $y=f(x)$ satisfies $$xf'(x)-2f(x)=x^4 f(x)^2$$ and given that $f(1)=-6$ and $x$ belongs to all positive real numbers then prove that $f'(3^{1/5}) =8$
I have tried in this way......
Given $$xf'(x)-2f(x)=x^4 f(x)^2$$
since $f(x)=y$ the equation can be written as $$x(dy/dx)-2y=x^4 y^2$$ I am stuck here please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $y=x^2z$. The equation becomes $x^3z'=x^8z^2$, so for $x\ne0$ we have $z'/z^2=x^5$. Integrating: $1/z=-\frac{1}{6}x^6+C'$, so $z=-\frac{6}{x^6+C}$. Hence $y=\frac{6x^2}{C-x^6}$. But $y(1)=-6$, so $C=0$ and hence $y=-\frac{6}{x^4}$ and so $y'=\frac{24}{x^5}$. Hence at $x=3^{1/5}$ we have $y=8$.